# MS Access - Complete table with column value from other table

Tags: ms-access

My *MainTable* contains tasks, one of the colums speciefies the *TaskType* as a string. The *TaskType* must be selected from the *ValidTasks* table, which contains different task types.

The *ValidTasks* table also contains a column called *Priority* which is an integer.

Now I want my MainTable to include the priority of the selected task. So that when I select as task from *ValidTasks* the corresponding Priority is added to another column in *MainTable*.

In the following step I will create a query showing the highest priority figure for each *Person* (also in the *MainTable*), so if it is easier to approach though a query then that would work for me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can go about this. The one I would go for unless there are overriding factors would be to use a `SELECT` query that links the two tables and has the fields I want as my "Main Table".

That is by far the best way. The alternative is to use the trigger of the user making a selection for a `TaskType` to look up and populate a field in your main table. I would not recommend that as it will come back to bite you as your database gets more complicated.

Also, I would not use a text field for `TaskType`. Your tables should have an `AutoNumber` as primary key and that is the field you should always use to link data from one table to another.

Comment: OK, so I create a query which grabs the _Tasks_ column and the _TaskType_ column from my _MainTable_.  
  
Now I want this query to have a column which does a lookup for each row to get the _Priority_ connected to each _TaskType_.  
  
This _Priority_ is stored in the table _ValidTasks_, how do I set up this column in the query?

Comment: This is pretty basic. I don't know if this will help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qceAxjRciXI I have not actually watched it I just googled it.

Comment: That's almost got me there!

Comment: That's almost got me there!
For all tasks in my MainTable with an assigned TaskType I now get the corresponding priority.
However, if a TaskType is not selected in the MainTable it does not show up.
I have an entry in my ValidTasks with a blank row and priority 6, but this does not get carried over, seems it doesn't look up fields in the MainTable that are blank.

Comment: You have to change the type of relationship between the two tables, Double click on the line that links the two tables in the query editor and it will give you the option to select all from one table and only those from the second table that match, instead of only those where there are matching values on both tables.